# Disable all actions on elements inside a container

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm implementing an interactive tutorial for a js-heavy web application. I highlight some container and expect the user to click on some element inside it. At the same time, I want to prevent the user from doing anything else, e.g. clicking on a different link.

The main problem is that I don't want to unbind any events - when the tutorial's closed, the application must work like it did before.

I started with registering a handler on all the containter's descendant elements:

```
element.on("click.tutorialLock", function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Then I set its "priority", so that it executes before any other events:

```
handlers = element.data("events").click;
our = handlers.pop();
handlers.splice(0, 0, our);
```

Finally, when I want to unlock some element, I just disable the event on it:

```
elementToEnable.off(".tutorialLock")
```

That works, but is very heavy. I tried registering the event only on elements which have some custom event handlers defined, but it omits anchors and other basic elements. Maybe you could come up with some good idea?

Comment: How about a combination of a modal box for the container your user is working with and the block UI plugin?

Comment: I haven't heard of it, I might give it a try. I'd be glad to hear some "raw" solution though, without using quite a big plugin ;).

Answer (score 0):

I would get the active parent element and pass it into a function which would disable every event other than the events in parent

```
$('.className').live ('click', function (e)
{
if (!$(this).parents('#targetParent').length))
    return false; // same as e.preventDefault() & e.stopPropogation()
});
```

Hope this is similar to what you want

Comment: `live` is deprecated - use `on` with delegation

Comment: `live` calls `on`, so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: I'm not sure if registering a delegated event makes sense here. I need my handler to be the first one to execute and block the rest and in this case I would only disable bubbling the event up when it reaches the parent - handlers defined on its children would still execute. Or am I wrong?